# Invalid outpath name using os.path.basename

Tags: python, netcdf, os.path

I have a problem with a Python code that is not creating an output netcdf file that I need, the code is too long but the basic idea is:

```
 module import part
 vrs = !ls -d /home/files/out
 vrspatterns = [vr + 'FILE_2015????' for vr in vrs]
 vrsoutpaths = ['finalfile_vr' + os.path.basename(vr) + 2012_ftests.nc for vr in vrs]
 qrs = !ls -d /home/files/out/second
 qrspatterns = [qr + 'FILE_2015_2????' for qr in qrs]
 qrsoutpaths = ['finalfile_qr' + os.path.basename(qr) + 2012_ftests2.nc for qr in qrs]
 inpatterns = vrspatterns + qrspatterns
 outpaths = vrsoutpaths + qrsoutpaths
```

MORE CODING THAT DOES NOT CRASH

```
 for inpattern, outpath in zip(inpattern,outpaths)
      cmd= 'ncgen ...'
      f = Dataset(outpath, 'a')
```

So, when it starts to run, the error is:

```
 netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4.c:22731)()

 RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

and it crashes on the line f = Dataset(outpath, 'a'). I am unable to find what is wrong with outpath that makes it invalid and in consequence is not generating the file at cmd.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should add "print outpath" before "f = Dataset(outpath, 'a')" so you can look at outpath before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in append mode`a` and in your explanation, you say you are trying to create the file. Reproducing this behavior raises the same error your are citing:

```
In [1]: import netCDF4

In [2]: netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc', 'a')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-aa44b76f4b7f> in <module>()
----> 1 netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc', 'a')

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:9689)()

RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

Try opening the file in write mode `netCDF4.Dataset(outpath, 'w')`.  Also, @david-cullen's suggestion to print out the `outpath` before opening the file is a good one.